# Replace dual-port RAM with two single port RAMs for J1 Forth CPU on Altera FPGA

Tags: verilog, forth

The wonderful J1 Forth CPU ([Verilog source code](http://www.excamera.com/files/j1demo/verilog/j1.v)) is given to work on Xilinx FPGA. I was trying to port it to an Altera Cyclone II FPGA.

I have difficulty getting the Altera dual-port RAM megafunction to work properly. Judging from the Verilog code, can I use two single port RAMs, instead of a dual port RAM?

The real questions is, does J1 Forth modify its own code while running? If not, why not separate the dual-port RAM into the code RAM (addressed by {_pc}) and the data RAM (addressed by _st0[15:1])?

Comment: Do you have access to a single-port ram that can do parallel read and write to any two address?

Answer (score 1):

Right now the compiler that produces code for the J1 (you should have gotten some Forth code that runs under Gforth) assumes that both data and code are coming from the same RAM space.  In order to separate code and data (which you would have to do in order to use separate RAM banks for each) you would have to modify the compiler to put anything done with CREATE into the data RAM.

You would also have to change the definition of ! and @ to fetch from the appropriate RAM bank. And forget implementing any sort of interactive prompt that allows you to define any new words, because that would require either writing to the RAM bank that contains code, or being able to point the PC at the data RAM bank, which defeats the purpose of having two RAM banks in the first place.

Otherwise you would have to wire up some sort of logic to keep the two RAM banks in sync.

The J1 is pretty tightly bound to the idea of having a dual-port RAM bank.